# PHP Parse Error unexpected '{'

Tags: php, parsing

I'm getting a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in line 2". And I don't see the problem.

```
<?php
class pointLocation {
    var $pointOnVertex = true; // Check if the point sits exactly on one of the vertices

    function pointLocation() {
    }
    
    
        function pointInPolygon($point, $polygon, $pointOnVertex = true) {
        $this->pointOnVertex = $pointOnVertex;
        
        // Transform string coordinates into arrays with x and y values
        $point = $this->pointStringToCoordinates($point);
        $vertices = array(); 
        foreach ($polygon as $vertex) {
            $vertices[] = $this->pointStringToCoordinates($vertex); 
        }
        
        // Check if the point sits exactly on a vertex
        if ($this->pointOnVertex == true and $this->pointOnVertex($point, $vertices) == true) {
            return "vertex";
        }
        
        // Check if the point is inside the polygon or on the boundary
        $intersections = 0; 
        $vertices_count = count($vertices);
    
        for ($i=1; $i < $vertices_count; $i++) {
            $vertex1 = $vertices[$i-1]; 
            $vertex2 = $vertices[$i];
            if ($vertex1['y'] == $vertex2['y'] and $vertex1['y'] == $point['y'] and $point['x'] > min($vertex1['x'], $vertex2['x']) and $point['x'] < max($vertex1['x'], $vertex2['x'])) { // Check if point is on an horizontal polygon boundary
                return "boundary";
            }
            if ($point['y'] > min($vertex1['y'], $vertex2['y']) and $point['y'] <= max($vertex1['y'], $vertex2['y']) and $point['x'] <= max($vertex1['x'], $vertex2['x']) and $vertex1['y'] != $vertex2['y']) { 
                $xinters = ($point['y'] - $vertex1['y']) * ($vertex2['x'] - $vertex1['x']) / ($vertex2['y'] - $vertex1['y']) + $vertex1['x']; 
                if ($xinters == $point['x']) { // Check if point is on the polygon boundary (other than horizontal)
                    return "boundary";
                }
                if ($vertex1['x'] == $vertex2['x'] || $point['x'] <= $xinters) {
                    $intersections++; 
                }
            } 
        } 
        // If the number of edges we passed through is even, then it's in the polygon. 
        if ($intersections % 2 != 0) {
            return "inside";
        } else {
            return "outside";
        }
    }

    
    
    function pointOnVertex($point, $vertices) {
        foreach($vertices as $vertex) {
            if ($point == $vertex) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    
    }
        
    
    function pointStringToCoordinates($pointString) {
        $coordinates = explode(" ", $pointString);
        return array("x" => $coordinates[0], "y" => $coordinates[1]);
    }
    
    
}



$pointLocation = new pointLocation();
$points = array("30 19", "0 0", "10 0", "30 20", "11 0", "0 11", "0 10", "30 22", "20 20");
$polygon = array("10 0", "20 0", "30 10", "30 20", "20 30", "10 30", "0 20", "0 10", "10 0");
foreach($points as $key => $point) {
    echo "$key ($point) is " . $pointLocation->pointInPolygon($point, $polygon) . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks,

-Laxmidi

Comment: What version of PHP on what platform are you running? Seems like on of the famous PHP phase of the moon bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine on my end, so it sounds like an encoding or EOL problem. Try these things:

- Make sure your file is in UNIX EOL format. Each line should end with a line feed (LF)
- Make sure you don't have a BOM (byte order mark) in your files.
- You can try getting rid of the `?>` at the end of your file. It serves no purpose. Granted, this won't really help to solve your problem, but it will make your code a little cleaner.
- Try adding a line break after your opening `<?php` and after your `class pointLocation {`. Some versions of PHP trip up on weird whitespace.
- Make sure your file is in something standard, like UTF-8

A good editor to make sure your file meets these criteria is [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/). There are lots of options and they make it dead easy. Don't use plain old Notepad, because Microsoft locks you into CRLF format (not PHP-friendly) and doesn't give you control over encoding.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi mattbasta,

Thank you for the suggestions. It sounds like the code works for everyone else. I used Dreamweaver to edit the code. How do I check the UNIX EOL format?

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 3):

Tested it. Runs without errors and produces the following outout:

```
0 (30 19) is boundary<br>1 (0 0) is outside<br>2 (10 0) is vertex<br>3 (30 20) is vertex<br>4 (11 0) is boundary<br>5 (0 11) is boundary<br>6 (0 10) is vertex<br>7 (30 22) is outside<br>8 (20 20) is inside<br>
```

(Mac OS x 10.6.3, PHP 5.3.1 cli)

**EDIT**: Maybe there cause for your error lies in some other part of your script that calls your class definition via include/require.

More info may help.

Comment: Tested on CentOS running PHP 5.3.1, I get identical output.

Comment: The author is having a problem; telling him that the problem he's experiencing doesn't exist doesn't help matters.

Comment: @mattbasta: Actually it does. By demonstrating that it works, we can assure him, that the code he has posted is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: Hi, 

I'm running it on my localhost which is a Mac.

-Laxmidi

Comment: Zach, Techpriester, and matbasta are all correct. I'm glad that the code works. But, I'm still stuck with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tested like Techpriester, runs without errors and produces the following output:

```
0 (30 19) is boundary<br>1 (0 0) is outside<br>2 (10 0) is vertex<br>3 (30 20) is vertex<br>4 (11 0) is boundary<br>5 (0 11) is boundary<br>6 (0 10) is vertex<br>7 (30 22) is outside<br>8 (20 20) is inside<br>
```

Tested on Ubuntu 9.10, Linux 2.6.31-17, PHP 5.3.2-0.dotdeb.2 (cli)

Try checking your php.ini for any [auto-prepended files](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) (auto_prepend_file) that may have that error.

Comment: Also, will be a good idea to check for previous includes (if they are present) in this same files.

Answer (score 0):

As the code worked for everyone else, I tried copying and pasting the code from Stackoverflow back into my system and it worked. Weird. I must have had something screwed up with the formatting.

I still don't know what the problem was, but at least it works.

Thank you mattbasta, Techpriester, and Zack.